# Using Callback in image loading (Sequential execution)

Tags: javascript, image, callback, synchronization

I am playing with image loading and stuck on sequentially executing the code

```
function processImage(callback) {
  console.log("Start");
  callback('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/');
  console.log("Finish");
}

function loadImage(url) {
   console.log('Load Method')
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = url;
   img.onload = function (event) {
      console.log('Image Loaded')
   }
}

processImage(loadImage);
```

For the above code, I want the output as Start -> Load Method -> Image Loaded -> Finish

Instead, I am getting Start -> Load Method -> Finish -> Image Loaded

I am having trouble using callback method I guess.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`img.onload` is setting an **event listener - so when the event occurs, it'll call the function**. So, unless your image loads in about a millionth of second (the amount of time I guess it takes JS to go to the next line), the `console.log("Finish")` will happen first.

When the image is fully loaded, the function which is set to `.onload` is called. As the image loads after JavaScript has processed the next line, this one will happen first. If you really want to indicate the start and finish, put your finish `console.log` after the image loaded `console.log`.

```js
img.onload = function (event) {
    console.log('Image Loaded')
    console.log('Finish)
}
```